# Higher-order optimal Runge-Kutta methods?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am aware of [Ralston's paper](https://doi.org/10.1090%2FS0025-5718-1962-0150954-0) on optimal (minimum truncation error) Runge-Kutta methods for orders up to 4 with the minimum number of stages for those orders. I have copied the Butcher tableaux of the methods he derived below:

**Order 1** (this one is trivial since Euler's method is the unique order-1 RK method)

```
 0 |
---+---
   | 1
```

**Order 2**

```
  0  |
     |
 2/3 | 2/3
-----+-----------
     | 1/4   3/4
```

**Order 3**

```
  0  |
     |
 1/2 | 1/2
     |
 3/4 |  0    3/4
-----+-----------------
     | 2/9   1/3   4/9
```

**Order 4**

```
       0        |
                |
      2/5       |         2/5
                |
 14 - 3 sqrt(5) | 1428 sqrt(5) - 2889    3785 - 1620 sqrt(5)
 -------------- | -------------------    -------------------
       16       |         1024                   1024
                |
                | 2094 sqrt(5) - 3365     975 + 3046 sqrt(5)    467040 + 203968 sqrt(5)
       1        | -------------------   - ------------------    -----------------------
                |         6040                   2552                    240845
----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                |   263 + 24 sqrt(5)     125 - 1000 sqrt(5)    3426304 + 1661952 sqrt(5)   30 - 4 sqrt(5)
                |   ----------------     ------------------    -------------------------   --------------
                |         1812                  3828                    5924787                  123
```

However, I have been unable to find any information in the literature regarding optimal 5th order (6-stage) methods or above; the closest thing I found was [Verner's repository of good embedded methods](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Ejverner/), but as far as I can tell those come with no guarantees of optimality for either the embedded method as a whole or either of the component methods.

Does anybody know of existing sources for minimum-error methods of order 5 or above and/or optimality proofs (or improvements on) Verner's methods?

Comment: You should watch this video (https://youtu.be/s_t6dIKjUUc?si=0-W5vwKXFrVeix4y&t=666) which talks about _modern_ optimized RK methods and the history of where coefficients came about for higher-order methods.

Comment: What is the objective function for the error minimization? The number of Butcher trees of a given order explodes exponentially with the order. How should one weight the coefficients to get an error measure that is valid? Each objective function will give a different optimum. For explicit methods the number of order conditions grows slower than the number of variables contained within. So you get an optimization problem with high-degree polynomial constraints, in high dimension, with a high number of free variables, all making the optimization task more difficult.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Honestly, I'm not sure; Ralston seemed to have some method for objective error minimization, so I assumed it would extend to higher-order methods. Thank you for pointing out that dependency.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Thanks for that resource! It seems quite helpful.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou looking through the video you provided, it appears that there was some set of equations which they optimized the error bounds for using Mathematica, but I am still unclear on what those equations are or (as per LutzLehmann 's comment) if they are even canonical measures of error bounds.

Comment: @Mel - https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/rk_derivation_0.pdf is an example of the process of deriving the coefficients of RK methods. Also [page 11 of this lecture notes](https://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs471/rungekutta.pdf) shows  the equations for a lower order method.